# Complex SOQL query

Tags: soql

I have the following structure:

`Contract__c (1) ----- (*) ContractCover__c (1) ---- (*) Address__c`

I need to create a query that gets all the addresses that are linked to contract via contractcover.

`Select Id, (Select Id FROM ContractCover__r, (Select Id from Contract__r)) From Address__c`

This query seems to be incorrect. Can anyone help?
Tia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only go one level of children down, so consider something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Address__r.Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contracts__r) 
FROM ContractCover__c 
WHERE Address__r.Id != null
```

If you need to limit it by a field on Address__c, you can add something like, `AND Address__r.XYZ__c = :foo`

Also note that the relationship name to Contract is likely `Contracts__r` not `Contract__r`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried anything like this but in parent to child relationship queries, you need to use plural of child names. Try something like:

```
Select Id, (Select Id FROM ContractCovers__r, (Select Id from Contracts__r)) From Address__c
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm):
You can only select children not grandchildren records.  You can go the opposite way and query the grandchildren directly and get the parent information as part of the query. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582375/salesforce-and-soql-accessing-a-grandchild-object-from-the-grandparent) that might help you structure your query. Found another similar question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36834/how-to-get-nested-children-records-more-than-1-level-deep-via-soql) too.

> **Understanding Relationship Query Limitations**
>
> When designing relationship queries, consider these limitations:
>
> Relationship queries are not the same as SQL joins. You must have a
>   relationship between objects to create a join in SOQL.
>
> No more than 35 child-to-parent relationships can be specified in a
>   query. A custom object allows up to 25 relationships, so you can
>   reference all the child-to-parent relationships for a custom object in
>   one query.
>
> No more than 20 parent-to-child relationships can be specified in a
>   query.
>
> In each specified relationship, no more than five levels can be
>   specified in a child-to-parent relationship. For example,
>   Contact.Account.Owner.FirstName (three levels).
>
> ***In each specified relationship, only one level of parent-to-child
>   relationship can be specified in a query. For example, if the FROM
>   clause specifies Account, the SELECT clause can only specify the
>   Contact or other objects at that level. It could not specify a child
>   object of Contact.***